# How do I populate Items in collection view from model view if I am using file picker?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am trying to select some files from file picker . Once I select them I want to show them in my collection view. If I am trying to achieve this thing from code behind then it is working fine but if I am trying it from MVVM then it is not populating the files I have selected.
and the reason I am trying to do it with MVVM is that I want to navigate to the next page with all selected files.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

MainPage.xaml

```
 <CollectionView   Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                        SelectionMode="Single"  x:Name="myCollection" 
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource appDataTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

</CollectionView>
```

Here I have binded my context.
MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage(FileViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
}
```

And this is my viewModel:`[ObservableProperty]
List sourceData;

```
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get { return sourceData; }
        set 
        { 
            sourceData = value; 
        
        }
    }
    public FileViewModel(IFolderPicker folderPicker)
    {
         sourceData = Items ;
        _folderPicker = folderPicker;
    }`

 public async void Add_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, 
        IEnumerable<String>>
    {
       //logic
    });
        var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = CustomFileType,
        });
        sourceData = null;
        foreach (var result in results)
        {

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FullPath);


            double size = fileSize(fileInfo);
            bool fileExist = false;
            if (Items != null)
            {
                foreach (Item item in Items)
                {
                    if (item.FilePath.Equals(result.FullPath))
                    {
                        fileExist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Items= new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            }
            if (!fileExist)
            {
                Items.Add(new Item
                {
                    FilePath = result.FullPath,
                    FileSize = size
                });
            }
            else
            {

              Items= sourceData;
                //   await DisplayAlert("Alert", "File already exist!", "Ok");
            }
        }

        Items = sourceData;

    }
```

Same code is working file if I put the view models code in code behind like below:

```
private async void Add_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, 
      IEnumerable<String>>
    {
        { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[]{"ics"} },
    });
    var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
    {
        FileTypes = CustomFileType,
    });
    myCollection.ItemsSource = null;
    foreach (var result in results)
    {

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FullPath);


        double size = fileSize(fileInfo);
        bool fileExist = false;
        foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            if (item.FilePath.Equals(result.FullPath))
            {
                fileExist = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!fileExist)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                FilePath = result.FullPath,
                FileSize = size
            });
        }
        else
        {
            myCollection.ItemsSource = Items;
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "File already exist!", "Ok");
        }
    }
    myCollection.ItemsSource = Items;

}
```

But it is not working with file view model.
I am not able to populate the collection view from view model.

Comment: Can you show me what your VM code looks like?

Comment: you need to initialize `Items` **once** in your constructor, and then use the `Add` method to add items to it.  It you initialize it again, you will break the existing binding.  Alternatively you can use INPC and raise a `PropertyChanged` event in the setter

Comment: @PreetiJadhav Add it to your question i can't read code in a comment

Comment: @FreakyAli I have added it in my question can you please check it once ?